# How could I send a delayed message in rabbitmq using the rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange plugin?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have installed the plugin to send a delayed message from here [rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange).

I couldn't find any help for using it in python. I've just started using rabbitmq .

Here is what I've been trying:

```
import pika  
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare("test-x", type="x-delayed-message", arguments={"x-delayed-type":"direct"})  
channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue',durable=True)
channel.queue_bind(queue="task_queue", exchange="test-x", routing_key="task_queue")
channel.basic_publish(exchange='test-x',routing_key='task_queue',body='Hello World! Delayed',arguments={"x-delay":100})
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World! Delayed'")
connection.close()
```

Here are the exchanges listed:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_exchanges
Listing exchanges ...
amq.direct  direct
test-x  x-delayed-message
amq.fanout  fanout
amq.match   headers
amq.headers headers
    direct
amq.rabbitmq.trace  topic
amq.topic   topic
amq.rabbitmq.log    topic
```

I don't have a good idea how I could pass a delay argument to the basic_publish function

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the `x-delay` header to your message properties and specify the delay value in milliseconds. Try this:

```
channel.basic_publish(
    exchange='test-x',
    routing_key='task_queue',
    body='Hello World! Delayed',
    properties=pika.BasicProperties(headers={"x-delay": 1000})
)
```

Comment: It does work. Will be checking now for the delay . Great

Comment: How to use this x-delay when resending the message after consumer failed?

Answer (score 4):

you can actually delay message without using plugin.
Message in Rabbit queue can be delayed in 2 ways 
     - using QUEUE TTL 
     - using Message TTL
If all messages in queue are to be delayed for fixed time use queue TTL.
If each message has to be delayed by varied time use Message TTL.
I have explained it using python3 and pika module.
pika BasicProperties argument 'expiration' in milliseconds has to be set to delay message in delay queue.
After setting expiration time, publish message to a delayed_queue ("not actual queue where consumers are waiting to consume") , once message in delayed_queue expires, message will be routed to a actual queue using exchange 'amq.direct'

```
def delay_publish(self, messages, queue, headers=None, expiration=0):
    """
    Connect to RabbitMQ and publish messages to the queue
    Args:
        queue (string): queue name
        messages (list or single item): messages to publish to rabbit queue
        expiration(int): TTL in milliseconds for message
    """
    delay_queue = "".join([queue, "_delay"])
    logging.info('Publishing To Queue: {queue}'.format(queue=delay_queue))
    logging.info('Connecting to RabbitMQ: {host}'.format(
        host=self.rabbit_host))
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(
       RABBIT_MQ_USER, RABBIT_MQ_PASS)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
       rabbit_host, RABBIT_MQ_PORT,
        RABBIT_MQ_VHOST, credentials, heartbeat_interval=0)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=queue, durable=True)

    channel.queue_bind(exchange='amq.direct',
                       queue=queue)
    delay_channel = connection.channel()
    delay_channel.queue_declare(queue=delay_queue, durable=True,
                                arguments={
                                    'x-dead-letter-exchange': 'amq.direct',
                                    'x-dead-letter-routing-key': queue
                                })

    properties = pika.BasicProperties(
        delivery_mode=2, headers=headers, expiration=str(expiration))

    if type(messages) not in (list, tuple):
        messages = [messages]

    try:
        for message in messages:
            try:
                json_data = json.dumps(message)
            except Exception as err:
                logging.error(
                    'Error Jsonify Payload: {err}, {payload}'.format(
                        err=err, payload=repr(message)), exc_info=True
                )
                if (type(message) is dict) and ('data' in message):
                    message['data'] = {}
                    message['error'] = 'Payload Invalid For JSON'
                    json_data = json.dumps(message)
                else:
                    raise

            try:
                delay_channel.basic_publish(
                    exchange='', routing_key=delay_queue,
                    body=json_data, properties=properties)
            except Exception as err:
                logging.error(
                    'Error Publishing Data: {err}, {payload}'.format(
                        err=err, payload=json_data), exc_info=True
                )
                raise

    except Exception:
        raise

    finally:
        logging.info(
            'Done Publishing. Closing Connection to {queue}'.format(
                queue=delay_queue
            )
        )
        connection.close()
```

Comment: Didn't know that. Though its been long, will make use of it next time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: TTL is time to expire a message, delayed message is time to have message delayed as it appears in the queue. Both are different.