# How can you Implement a Exchange Header with RabbitMQ in Golang?

Tags: go, rabbitmq

so currently I'm working with RabbitMQ and Golang. I started the tutorial on the RabbitMQ Homepage and created Queues and Exchanges. But I couldn't find any tutorial which explains how to implement a Exchange Header in Golang.

The important stuff is that I also would like to know, is how to put Data in the Header for example a ID and a Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean name of the queue or exchange. You can iterate through a list, or just type it in statically if name never changes. For example, I created x amount of queues based off CPU's to send the data in parallel to each core while in series (Each queue runs on its own thread). Might not be the best approach it was my approach, and added a third layer that wasn't obviously build in, round-robin in series to the queues!

```
 package main
    
    import (
        "log"
    
        "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    )
    
    var i int = 0
    var coreCount []string = make([]string, runtime.NumCPU())
   
 func main() {
        //Make a connection
        conn, _ := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
        defer conn.Close()
    
        //Ccreate a channel
        ch, _ := conn.Channel()
        defer ch.Close()
    
        //Declare a queue
        q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
            "hello", // Your Queue name is "hello" bound to the Default Exchange <------ q.Name is Defined here
            false,   // should the message be persistent? also queue will survive if the cluster gets reset
            false,   // autodelete if there's no consumers (like queues that have anonymous names, often used with fanout exchange)
            false,   // exclusive means I should get an error if any other consumer subsribes to this queue
            false,   // no-wait means I don't want RabbitMQ to wait if there's a queue successfully setup
            nil,     // arguments for more advanced configuration
        )
    
        //Publish a message
        body := "hello world"
        err = ch.Publish(
            "",     // exchange <--- change the header here
            q.Name, // routing key 
            false,  // mandatory
            false,  // immediate
            amqp.Publishing{
                ContentType: "text/plain",
                Body:        []byte(body),
            })
        log.Printf("Message: %s", body)
    
    }
```

q.Name is your queue name and channel that you are binding to..
"" : // Exchange is your exchange name.. When left with double quotes it's name is defaulted and binds all queues with the same routing key to that exchange.

Look at the delcareQueue(arg), that is where you change the queue name.
And in the publish(arg), that is where you change the Exchange headers.. You could make a list of several exchanges and iterate through that list as well.

**EDIT** You need to read your messages on the publisher side.

I have 5 color queues setup.
If a message is red, it goes to the red queue, blue to the blue queue..

So your publisher needs to read each message, convert  the byte type to a string, then parse the message for whatever your requirements are. Assume you are looking for red messages.

Your publisher found a red message now it needs to direct it to the red queue. This is where you update the QUEUE name in the declareQueue() based off an array list of all the queue's names and where the color in the message matches the queue name, now your updating the header message as the message is coming in.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
[image: EXAMPLE]

Where images is the publisher, reading each messages and directing to each queue.

Comment: I was also this far, but in this instance it's just defining the Queue, but I need to make a Exchange Header. I already declared a Exchange Topic for example, so i have a little Idea how it could work. But I want to know how this Header is built and defined?

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

Comment: I made an update hopefully that clarifies it for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449234/how-could-i-send-a-delayed-message-in-rabbitmq-using-the-rabbitmq-delayed-messag?rq=1